# How Can I list files in the same order that flyway executes them in bash?

Tags: bash, find, flyway, ls

I have flyway migration scripts, which are named as follows.

```
V1__description.sql
V2.001__description.sql
V2.002__description.sql
V2__description.sql
```

The above is the order which they are listed by ls, or the default sort order of find. The order in which they are executed by flyway are

```
V1__description.sql
V2__description.sql
V2.001__description.sql
V2.002__description.sql
```

Is there a way to use the bash sort command to list the files in the order in which flyway executes them? The files cannot be renamed.

Comment: The term »the order in which they are listed in bash« is unclear.  What do you enter to get this list?  `ls` is not part of `bash`.  Are you using `echo *` or similar to list them?

Comment: Edited for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is "No. At least, not by itself."

First off, there is no "bash sort command". The `sort` command is not actually part of bash, it's a separate tool provided by your operating system. While its usage varies by operating system, no version that I'm aware of would sort your input the way you're asking for.<sup>[1]</sup> Find out more about its capabilities by running [`man sort`](http://man.freebsd.org/sort) in your shell.

One option might be to stream your file list through something that makes it sortable, then stream it through the reverse conversion after sort:

```
$ sed 's/^\(V[0-9]\)_/\1.000_/' files.txt | sort -n | sed 's/^\(V[0-9]\)\.000_/\1_/'
```

<sub>[1] I'd love to be corrected on this point.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I guess flyway first executes `V2__description.sql` and then `V2.001__*.sql` etc. because they are logically to be applied later?  Then you can change their names for sorting (and change them back right *after* sorting):

```
(
  echo "V1__description.sql"
  echo "V2.001__description.sql"
  echo "V2.002__description.sql"
  echo "V2__description.sql"
) | sed 's/\./_DOT_/g' | sort | sed 's/_DOT_/./g'
```

This will change all dots to `_DOT_` for sorting and change it back again afterwards.

If you have more complex things to accomplish (like the sort order of underscores, dashes, dots and plus signs shall be `+_-.`) you can change more of them to and fro:

```
… | sed -e 's/_/_1UNDERSCORE_/g' \
        -e 's/\+/_0PLUS_/g' \
        -e 's/-/_2DASH_/g' \
        -e 's/\./_3DOT_/g' \
  | sort \
  | sed -e 's/_3DOT_/\./g' \
        -e 's/_2DASH_/-/g' \
        -e 's/_0PLUS_/\+/g' \
        -e 's/_1UNDERSCORE_/_/g'
```

Note that converting the underscore needs to be done first (and reverted last) to not confuse the other converted specially treated characters which are converted later (and reverted earlier).